# What is the reason for the Ajax call is not working in some ips but it works in other ips

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax call like:

```
https://test.com/index.php?op=ajax&page=2&limit=10
```

It's working on my IP. But it's not working in my coworker's systems. What is the reason for this? I didn't see this issue before.

Comment: First guess would be a firewall issue, but it would depend on what you mean by "not working". Does your coworker get a connection error/network timeout or does the PHP script execute but output incorrect/different results?

Comment: Yes. they got the default value. I set the default value if the ajax request is not working.

Comment: What default value? Something from the PHP script or something you set in your javascript code that's executing this request?

Comment: I set the redirection in php. They got the redirection in ajax result.

Comment: If this is a firewall issue, then how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is there any mysql query issue? I think the query takes some time, then redirection will happen

Comment: Yes, In this case my query takes some 1. ms time. Is this a problem?